# Generate random numbers after a string

Tags: python, random

I'm currently trying to write a script that will allow generating random numbers before a string, I expect to have lines of code which have my random numbers + the string for 
ex: 
"328188123@gmail.com"
"283821813@gmail.com"
 I'm currently a beginner and so if anyone can help that would be great. I've tried to resolve my issue by figuring out a way to implement the random function before the string but I can't seem to find a-way.

```
import random
print(random.randint(0,100000))

G = "@gmail.com"
```

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-generate-random-numbers-in-python/

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar He already knows how to generate them, he just doesn't know how to get them into the string.

Comment: @Barmar It’s not clear from the question, so that’s why I put the link in a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: Why’d every email be gmail?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar He's already calling `random.randint()`. What is he going to learn from that page?

Comment: @Barmar He might learn that asking a clear question has a better chance of getting a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the random integer to a variable, then format it into the string.

```
import random
r = random.randint(0, 100000)
g = '%d@gmail.com' % r
print(g)
```

Comment: Or using f-string, `f”{random.randint(100000)}@gmail.com”`, but hard coding the gmail domain seems pretty lame for the OP, since not every email in the world is gmail, at least not yet.

Comment: Why `%s`, not `%d` or `%i`?

Comment: @HeapOverflow That was a mistake.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar There are lots of formatting methods in Python, I don't see the need to mention multiple.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you do.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below,

```
import random
g = '{}@gmail.com'.format(random.randint(0, 100000))
print(g)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import random
r = random.randint(0,100000)
G = str(r) + "@gmail.com"
print(G)
```